# Query get group base on a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, querying

I have the following table (TableOne):

```
GroupId         TradeId     Status
16848           78          LIVE
16848           79          LIVE
16848           80          LIVE
16848           81          DELETED
16841           82          DELETED
16841           83          LIVE
```

I need to get the whole group value when given the deleted Trade Id?
Is there a simple way to do this? I tried to do some query, but in the end I don't know where to start.

Thanks for the reply guys, maybe i over simplified my problem. Here's more details

The trade Id comes from another mapping table (TableCorrect):

```
OriginalTradeId     NewTradeId  
100                 81
101                 90
102                 91
```

I'm given the original TradeId and need to join with "TableCorrect" with "TableOne"

```
Select * 
from TableOne 
inner join TableCorrect on TableOne.TradeId=TableCorrect.NewTradeID
where TableCorrect.OriginalTradeId={@PassedInValue}
```

But the above only gives me the deleted entry, but i want the rest of the trades from Table one with the same GroupId

So given OriginalTradeId=100

I want the following output:

```
   GroupId         TradeId      Status
    16848           78          LIVE
    16848           79          LIVE
    16848           80          LIVE
    16848           81          DELETED
```

Thanks and Regards,

Kev

Comment: Please include your desired output as well as the query you've tried so far that isn't working.  You should also indicate which database you are working with, ideally via tagging.

Comment: So if given `82` you want to return both records for group id `16841`?

Answer (score 1):

I think a `where` clause with a subquery might be the simplest solution:

```
Select t1.*
from TableOne t1
where t1.GroupId = (select top 1 GroupId
                    from TableOne tt1 join
                         TableCorrect tc
                         on tt1.TradeId = tc.NewTraceId
                    where tc.OriginalTradeId = @PassedInValue
                   );
```

This is not the only way.  Another interesting way uses window functions:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             max(case when tc.OriginalTradeId = @PassedInValue then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by t1.GroupId) as HasOriginalTrade
      from TableOne t1 join
           TableCorrect tc
           on t1..TradeId = tc.NewTradeId
     ) t1
where HasOriginalTrade > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @myTradeId INT;
SET @myTradeId = 1;

SELECT *
    FROM TableOne
    WHERE GroupId = (SELECT GroupId
                        FROM TableOne
                            WHERE TradeId = @myTradeId)
```